# Justifying the result of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \tfrac{3^x}{4^x}$

Tags: limits

I am working with the next limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3^x}{4^x}$$

I intuitively know that since

$$3^x< 4^x$$

when $x$ tends to infinite,
the result of the limit is:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3^x}{4^x}=0$$

However, I need a some more mathematical justification rather than the intuitive justification, I would appreciate any help or hint to justify this result, the l'Hospital's rule doesn't work for this limit, since if I apply the rule, the limit remains similar.

Comment: Knowing that $f(x) < g(x)$ does not imply that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$.  For example $x < x + 1$, but $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x + 1} = 1$.  All you can say is that if $f(x) < g(x)$ (for all sufficiently large values of $x$) and the limit $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say
$$y=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3^x}{4^x}$$
We then have
$$y=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x$$
We then take the natural log of both sides:
$$\ln y=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
Since
$$\frac{3}{4}<1\text{ and }\ln x <0 \text{ if }x<1$$
As $x\to\infty$, the right side of the equation goes to $-\infty$. Taking
$$y=e^{\ln y}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}$$
gets us
$$y=0$$
This isn't intuitive, but it's certainly mathematically justifiable.

Comment: Notation is misleading. $e^{-\infty}$ suggests at arithmetic with $\infty$.

Comment: @REr I fixed it.

Comment: thanks for the support, I think that is a very complex approach.

Comment: @Neo Normally the word "complex" is used for things related to [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\frac{3^x}{4^x}=\left(\frac34\right)^x$$and use the fact that $\frac34<1$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3^x}{4^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x=0$$

Because $\left(\tfrac34\right)^x$ is decreasing to $0$, as exponential function $a^x$ with $a=\tfrac34<1$.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I didn't try that very useful approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just work out the division: it's $(3/4)^x$ which is a decreasing exponential.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\frac{3^x}{4^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\space\exp\left(x\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\space x\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$\exp\left(\ln\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\lim_{x\to\infty}\space x\right)=\exp\left(-\ln\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\lim_{x\to\infty}\space x\right)=0$$

---

With some strange looking math ($\infty$ isn't a number)

$$\exp\left(-\infty\right)=e^{-\infty}=\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=0$$